# how to use infomap community detection using cdlib

Tags: python, networkx

I have installed cdlib for community detection and tried to use `infomap`  to get the communities from a `networkx` graph

```py
from cdlib import algorithms
import networkx as nx
G = nx.karate_club_graph()
coms = algorithms.infomap(G)
```

but I got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\a\desktop", line 686, in infomap
    raise ModuleNotFoundError("Optional dependency not satisfied: install package wurlitzer to use infomap.")
ModuleNotFoundError: Optional dependency not satisfied: install package wurlitzer to use infomap.
```

After that I installed `wurlitzer`, and `infomap` but the problem persists